# Looking to edit a webpage on wordpress that is created with bootstrap, trying to find the elements I need to edit within the Editor

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to edit a webpage of a friend created by a developer. A theme is installed on their WordPress dashboard however all the pages and particularly the homepage are either empty or don't match the front end.

I have looked at editing the theme that is installed however the homepage (under pages) is completely empty in the field and textbox, I believe that the previous developer has created their own theme in bootstrap and imported the theme into the editor. When I go under theme and CSS, there are several bootstrap files. However I can't seem to find where the HTML elements of the webpage are, I have used Google Chrome inspect to edit the elements however I need to find where they are located within the website itself to make permanent changes. There is also a carousel slider on the homepage (powered by SA sliders) that links to a portfolio page which opens a lightbox player of the video thumbnails in the carousel slider which I can't find the code for. barkingmouse.com.au is the website I am currently working on.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I've understood what you're trying to achieve_ so it's difficult to give you a helpful answer _ but if you're only asking for the location of .php files and WP style.css that you should edit then you need to find the theme folder _ 
In the website file structure you need to locate the following folder 'wp-content' _
open this and locate the folder 'themes' _
open this and locate the folder with the name of your theme _
the files you're looking to edit are inside

Comment: Yes I realised I haven't made myself entirely clear... basically I would normally edit a homepage of a WordPress site under pages -> home. However when I go under the home page in this website it is completely blank, when obviously the homepage is populated with a carousel and other images. I'm wanting to know where I can find the code for this homepage.

Comment: It sounds as though you are trying to access source code from the Wordpress dashboard _ If that is so then you are very 'wide of the mark' _ That's not how you deal with Wordpress code _ You need to access the files via a proper folder and file structure NOT the internal page structure _ Your access point on a live Wordpress site will be via file transfer protocol (ftp) NOT by logging in to wp-admin

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help me but I still don't think I am making myself clear. If you look at barkingmouse.com.au you will see a live website, with an SA slider, about section, watch section and more when you scroll down. Going here [link](https://imgur.com/kJ4UzJP) I can see none of that. Going into the theme's php I can't find any of the elements that I need to be able to edit that are on the homepage. Does that make more sense with screenshots included?

Comment: The image you have linked to is the Wordpress Home page_ which unfortunately simply confirms what I've been telling you about not accessing the files you need to edit _ It might help more if you open the installed plugins page on the dashboard & provide a screenshot of it _ just in case we can access the slider from there _ BUT understand this is a 'maybe' ONLY _ but do this first

Comment: hello again @Joseph _ Reading over your previous questions on SO I think it's probable that you may have misunderstood how Wordpress works _ You could describe a Wordpress site as working on 3 tiers _ Tier 1: the website visitor sees _ Tier 2: the Wordpress dashboard which you're trying to work from _  Tier 3: the layer you are trying to access to edit files _ You may be able to access some elements of Tier 3 via WP plugins & possibly from an access point provided by the Theme developer _ but you would have to know how to code php _ If you're still unable to resolve this email me : )

Comment: Thanks for all of your effort @Maik - would you happen to know about css and bootstrap grids?

Comment: I do indeed @Joseph _ but here's a link to W3 Schools explanation of the Bootstrap grid system which is useful because you can try out changes you make in the basic BS4 code _ If you have any issues then ask a new question on Stack Overflow AFTER you've checked out existing Q&As _ I can't really answer you here because we shouldn't turn this into a personal thread! But please don't delete this question or I will lose the reputation you just awarded me! : ( Thanks 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp  _ Good Luck ; )

Comment: Thanks again @maik, I was having issues posting a new thread but I switched to the traditional formatting and have been able to open a new one. I've already trawled through W3 and existing stackoverflow threads as well as others. Thanks!

Comment: ask a new question specific to Bootstrap 4 grid _ I'm online _ I'll see it ; )

Comment: I've just posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824149/image-elements-distorting-when-resizing-in-a-bootstrap-grid) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit the home page view then look for index.php file and if you want to edit the template post page then look for single.php file
You'll find html elements  in these files

And if you are looking for css files then he maybe have written styles in style.css file or he must have made a folder named css or sass

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually found the homepage formating in the the header.php file with the css under custom.css!

Comment: Glad to help you out !