# Image elements distorting when resizing in a Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [bootstrap grid set](https://barkingmouse.com.au/watch/) up to show 4 video thumbnails in a row (linking to a Lightbox to play the video) but the thumbnails are being squished. (Shared House Episodes) How can I crop the thumbnails instead?

The current code I have in place is

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="box-watch">
    <a id="videoid" href="#" description="videodescription." ref="videourl" class="watch-video" type="youtube" >
      <div class="box-watch-img">
        <img src="imagethumbnail.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="box-watch-internal">
        <div class="title">Episode 1</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

When I update the width to 33%, it gives me the correct looking dimensions, but obviously puts the grid out of whack. I don't mind if I have to crop the image rather than uniformly scale it down but no code I have tried so far is allowing me to achieve that.

I replaced the `width:25%` property with `object-fit: cover;` and the image just went full size rather than constrained in the column. I also tried adding the 'object-fit' beneath 'width' to use in conjunction but had no result either.

Comment: "_the thumbnails are being squished_" _ If your focus is on what's happening to the thumbnail images then that's what your code should be dealing with as well _ not the width of the col _ because Bootstrap deals with that automatically _ BUT I don't know of any way to actually crop the image! Try something with `img width` and / or `img max-width` _ Good Luck

Comment: I should have said to use the image class you've already set up `box-watch-img` _ work with the CSS specific to that element first

Comment: thinking more on cropping the image instead of resizing @Joseph _ If that's really what you want to achieve you may want to try something along the lines of `img min-width` and `img {overflow: hidden} ` **possibly** BUT I'm not certain about this at all _ I'm only suggesting an experimental direction for you to work on ; )

Comment: thanks @Maik but im not entirely sure where I need to be putting what. Do i need to change my img tag to read '<img min-width src="imagethumbnail.jpg">' and then put img '{overflow:hidden}' in my css side? I'm not sure if you're looking on the webpage but the CSS is effecting the '@media' so not sure if a specific img tag will work in my css panel...

Comment: Despite you adding the tag _ I'd forgotten you have the added WP complication : |
I don't have time to do the experiments with 'CSS3 cropping image' <<< (_possibly a useful Google phrase?_) _ If it was my experiment I'd set up a trial Bootstrap 4 page on my local machine then any results I liked I'd add to the live Wordpress files _ Media queries should be in **style.css** or where you found them before in **custom.css** _ `min-width` - belongs in CSS file @Joseph and the `img {overflow: hidden;}` was only a suggestion _ but you would add it to the CSS you have for `box-watch-img`

Comment: to clarify "add it to the CSS you already have for `box-watch-img` " _ You would add it like this `.box-watch-img img {min-width: whatever you want the minimum width to be; overflow:hidden;}` (added in the css file) BUT bear in mind this is a suggestion to experiment with NOT a solution! Good Luck ; )

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Maik, I have figured it out. I was right with adding the object-fit: cover. I was just inspecting the div class and adding the css property to that rather than the img src specifically.

Comment: so have you achieved the crop effect you were looking for @Joseph ? _ or just avoided the 'squished' look of the image? _ Also bear in mind that you can add your own answer to this question _ Make it useful for others ; ) I've upvoted the question _ providing your own answer will boost your numbers too ; )

Comment: Yes @Maik, achieved. :) I'll answer my own question - i didnt know if that was common practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure I had the image source selected to show me where the relevant CSS code was rather than having the entire div class selected allowed me to place the `object-fit: cover` tag and have it effect the relevant thumbnails in the table.